# How to create a separated indicator button in Android

Tags: android, button

What is a good way to create a separated indicator button like the example below in Android with all functionalities of a single button?

Does anyone maybe know a library which contains such a button?

[image: Example Button]

Comment: Hi. That question isn't a good way for asking. Take a look http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You could create a LinearLayout with two TextViews and then just override the onclick event of the LinearLayout. If you want to change backgrounds for the pressed and released look then override the ontouch.

There is also an option to create your own button by extending the View class.